# Can't find Python 3 folder on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm unable to find the python 3 folder on my Mac (Mojave). I have installed it correctly, and I've tried to reinstall it with but it says that it is already installed. I even installed a package (Mendel-development-tool) on it. Through my checking of the Mendel-development-tool (trying to uninstall it), it states that I have a folder with this:

```
/Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/bin/mdt
```

But, when I enter this path into my terminal, it shows python 2.7. And, when I look through to the site packages, mdt isn't there, and when I look through my library folder and see python, the only thing there is 2.7.

Does anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: How did you install python? I personally suggest that you use pyenv

Comment: Could you link an article on how to do this on the Mac, or describe how to do it? Thank you for the response!

Comment: If you search for pyenv, I think the instructions are fairly self explanatory

Comment: you should try typing 'which python' and see what you get. Then try 'which python3'

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how you installed python, but it could literally be installed anywhere on disk

If you want to find something use the `find` command

```
sudo find ~ -type f -name mdt
```

If that returns nothing, then mdt is not in your home folder

You can also find all directories with Python in the name

```
sudo find ~ -type d -iname '*python*'
```

Comment: with `-type f` the `mdt` would not show up even when exists but as a symlink.

Comment: @Marcin is it not an executable **file**?

Comment: It's just generic remark (I got no idea how `mdt` is  being set up) and all I was saying that `-type f` means `file` but **not** a symlink to a file. It may not be a problem in this particular case though (so I am not saying your answer is incorrect) - just flagging for potential readers that it often may be required to add `-type l` as well.

Comment: How about `locate mdt`?

Comment: yes, `locate` would work (assuming it is installed and database is up to date :) as it is pretty dumb, but it would also produce more noise, listing anything that contains `mdt` in path, so piping thur `grep` etc may be handy, which makes this simple task more complicated, esp. for newbies. But as I said - this is pretty academical debate now - your `find` example may perfectly address OP's need.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a python3 folder. What you probably want is the python3 application. Type

> which python3

and see what you get. In my case, I get the location of the python3 application. I also have the application python3.7. Once you find the location of these apps you can make sure the location is in your PATH.

Installing a python version does not create a python folder.

Comment: This is beside the point, but `type` is more helpful than `which`. It will show aliases, shell functions, and hashed paths in addition to executables. For more details see [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117037)